How to fix grid overlay issue when displaying PNG images in Fyne?
I'm working on a Go application using the fyne library to create a graphical user interface. When I try to display a PNG image, a grid overlay appears on top of the image. I've tried different methods to decode and display the image, but the grid persists. Here is a simplified version of my code:
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
    "image/png"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("Image Viewer")

    // Open the image file
    file, err := os.Open("path/to/image.png") // Set path
    if err != nil {
        fyne.LogError("Failed to open image", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Decode the image
    img, err := png.Decode(file)
    if err != nil {
        fyne.LogError("Failed to decode image", err)
        return
    }

    // Create a canvas image from the decoded image
    imageCanvas := canvas.NewImageFromImage(img)
    imageCanvas.FillMode = canvas.ImageFillContain
    imageCanvas.SetMinSize(fyne.NewSize(400, 300)) 

    // Create content container
    content := container.NewVBox(
        widget.NewLabel("Here is your image:"),
        imageCanvas,
    )

    // Set the content and size
    myWindow.SetContent(content)
    myWindow.Resize(fyne.NewSize(800, 600))
    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}


I've also tried using canvas.ImageFillStretch and canvas.ImageFillOriginal for the FillMode, tried to getting image by using canvas.NewImageFromFile, but neither resolves the issue. How can I fix this grid overlay problem and correctly display the PNG image in fyne? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Here's what it looks like now, I'm trying to get a transparent background instead of a PNG grid:

As a visual question it would be good to include a screenshot. It’s tough to imagine what a grid overlay could mean when the code does not include any grid or other visual items overlaid

@andy.xyz Thanks for the note, I added a screenshot.

The background grid is literally in your image. To have the image be transparent you will need to remove it, making those pixels transparent instead.
